# create Product gallery page with PHP

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, gallery

I'm very new to PHP and I have this assignment I need to do for school.
I have to create this product gallery page with PHP:

[image]

I need to get the product name, price, image and description out of a database.
Here is my database.

[image: Here is my database.]

Here is my products.php page:

```
<?php
  require "headers/header.php";
?>

 <?php
          if(isset($_SESSION['IdUsers'])) {
          echo '
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-3">

        <h1 class="my-4">Bright shop</h1>


      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->

      <div class="col-lg-9">
        <p></p>
        </div>

        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item One</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Two</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Three</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Four</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Five</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
            <div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt=""></a>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                  <a href="#">Item Six</a>
                </h4>
                <h5>$24.99</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet numquam aspernatur!</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">&#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

  </div>';
           }

          else {
           header("Location: index.php");
        }

        ?>

<?php
  require "footer.php";
?>
```

This is what I wrote:

```
  <?php
  Include_once "includes/dbhproducts.inc.php";
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_products");
  $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
  If ($resultcheck > 0) {
  While ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo         '<div class="card h-100">
              <a href="#"><img class="card-img-top" src="’.$row[“product_image”].’" alt=""></a>
              "<div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title"><a href="#">’.$row[“name”].’</a></h4>
                <h5’.$row[“price”].’</h5>
                <p class="card-text">’.$row[“product_desc”].’</p>
              </div>'
  }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome. Replace `’` with `'`. `<h5` is missing `>`. Your `<div class="card h-100">` is missing a closing `</div>`

Comment: whats up with the magic quotes, and you haven't told us what part you're having trouble with, is there an error?

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Instead of echoing large chunks of HTML through PHP, just close the PHP tag, write your HTML and open the PHP-tag again: `?> your htm <?php`. That will make the code much easier to read and debug since most IDE's will be able to syntax highlight the HTML as well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change your echo to this:

```
echo
"<div class='card h-100'>
 <a href=''><img class='card-img-top' src='".$row['product_image']."' alt=''></a>
 <div class='card-body'>
 <h4> class='card-title'><a href=''>".$row['name']."</a></h4>
 <h5>".$row['price']."</h5>
 <p class='card-text'>".$row['product_desc']."</p>
 </div>"
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Oh, yea.. Sorry about that.. Thanks